# Fluent Validation output current record information

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Ok, I am using Fluent Validation for one of my classes what I want to know is. How does one determine what record is at fault i.e say for example the following

Is being classed as a number that the customer can refer to how would I Change my string below using Fluent Validation to output the current record it's working on Document No to the customer.

```
  public string DocumentNo { get; set; }
```

Is it just as simple as appending it to the string?

Code:

```
  public  class SupplierTransactionsValidation : AbstractValidator<SageStandardImportInvoces>
  { 


     public SupplierTransactionsValidation()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.AnalysisCode1) // code repeated
                .NotEqual("None").WithMessage("Please enter a value for AnalysisCode1")
                .Length(0, 3);



            RuleFor(x => x.AnalysisCode2) // code repeated
                .NotEqual("None").WithMessage("Please enter a value for AnalysisCode2")
                .Length(0, 3);

            RuleFor(x => x.AnalysisCode3) // code repeated
                .NotEqual("None").WithMessage("Please enter a value for AnalysisCode3")
                .Length(0, 3);


        }
    }
```

Comment: How do the "AnalysisCode1-3" properties fit into this picture? Are you having problems with DocumentNo or the analysis code properties? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you could create a private method that gets the name of the property to be validated by casting the body of the expression to a `MemberExpression`:

```
public class SupplierTransactionsValidation : AbstractValidator<SageStandardImportInvoces>
{
    public SupplierTransactionsValidation()
    {
        BuildRule(x => x.AnalysisCode1);
        BuildRule(x => x.AnalysisCode2);
        BuildRule(x => x.AnalysisCode3);
    }

    private IRuleBuilderOptions<SageStandardImportInvoces, string> 
        BuildRule(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<SageStandardImportInvoces, string>> expression)
    {
        return RuleFor(expression)
            .NotEqual("None")
            .WithMessage($"Please enter a value for {(expression.Body as System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression)?.Member.Name}")
            .Length(0, 3);
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to repeat your logic.